# SQL JSON object return string for nested query with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I need help on SQL json nested object creation with UNION ALL, I have nested query and i want to pass some default objects to the query with using union all, but currently it returns string object for nested query.

Here is my query

```
Select * from (
SELECT 'Id'=      ent.categoryid , 
       'Text'=    ent.catname , 
       ques = json_query( 
       ( 
              SELECT * 
              FROM   ( 
                            SELECT 'Id'=   q.qid, 
                                   'Text'= q.questext
                            FROM   chatfaqquestionnaire q 
                            WHERE  q.categoryid = ent.categoryid 
                            UNION ALL 
                            SELECT top 1 
                            'Id'= 100000, 
                            'Text'='Talk to Agent'                                   
                            From   [mChatCategory] ent1 where ent1.CategoryId=ent.CategoryId 
                             ) AS t FOR json auto ) )
FROM   [mChatCategory] ent 
Union All
SELECT  top 1
        'Id'=100000 , 
        'Text'='Talk to Agent',
         ques=null      
              from  [mChatCategory] ent 
) AS L1  FOR json auto
```

and return json object as below

```
[{"Id":1,"Text":"Food Safety","ques":"[{\"Id\":100000,\"Text\":\"Talk to Agent\"}]"},{"Id":2,"Text":"Permit Releted","ques":"[{\"Id\":1,\"Text\":\"Permit not renewed\\r\\n\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Text\":\"Payment issue\"},{\"Id\":100000,\"Text\":\"Talk to Agent\"}]"}]
```

which is in wrong format for ques nested object.
Expected output:

```
[{"Id":1,"Text":"Food Safety","ques":[{"Id":100000,"Text":"Talk to Agent"}]},{"Id":2,"Text":"Permit Releted","ques":[{"Id":1,"Text":"Permit not renewed\r\n"},{"Id":2,"Text":"Payment issue"},{"Id":100000,"Text":"Talk to Agent"}]}]
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: That is a Valid JSON. What format are you expecting?

Comment: You mean that `SELECT  top 1 'Id'=100000 ,  'Text'='Talk to Agent',ques=null from  [mChatCategory] ent` makes `JSON` output not as you expect?

Comment: Yes if we use union all it doesn't return desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `FOR JSON AUTO`, `JSON` text is escaped. You may try to solve this issue using `JSON_QUERY` again.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#prevent-double-escaped-json-in-for-json-output):

> JSON_QUERY without its optional second parameter returns only the
>   first argument as a result. Since JSON_QUERY always returns valid
>   JSON, FOR JSON knows that this result does not have to be escaped.

```
    Select Id, Text, JSON_QUERY(ques) AS ques 
    from (
    SELECT 'Id'=      ent.categoryid , 
        'Text'=    ent.catname , 
        ques = json_query( 
        ( 
                SELECT * 
                FROM   ( 
                                SELECT 'Id'=   q.qid, 
                                    'Text'= q.questext
                                FROM   chatfaqquestionnaire q 
                                WHERE  q.categoryid = ent.categoryid 
                                UNION ALL 
                                SELECT top 1 
                                'Id'= 100000, 
                                'Text'='Talk to Agent'                                   
                                From   [mChatCategory] ent1 where ent1.CategoryId=ent.CategoryId 
                                ) AS t FOR json auto ) )
    FROM   [mChatCategory] ent 
    Union All
    SELECT  top 1
            'Id'=100000 , 
            'Text'='Talk to Agent',
            ques=null      
                from  [mChatCategory] ent 
    ) AS L1  FOR json auto
```

Comment: It returns me error with `Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 31
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'L2'.`

Comment: @Lifewithsun Can you check again, I've made an update. I've copied wrong code from my reproduction test statement.